# Invalid Argument Error: No OppKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNNV2'

Tags: python

Trying to run a machine learning code and wound up getting the error below when running the last section of the code. The error pops up not only in the last section of the code but also the section before it (Training), only after running the Prediction section.

When I originally downloaded the code from the web, it would not run at all. After some troubleshooting, I found a suggestion to load Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86). This allowed me to run most of the code. How do I fix this error?

'''

```
# Training

model.compile(
    loss='mean_squared_error', 
    optimizer='adam'
)

BATCH_SIZE = 64

history = model.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train, 
    epochs=50, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    shuffle=False,
    validation_split=0.1
)

model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

Epoch 1/50

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-16bf71f53dfc> in <module>
      8 BATCH_SIZE = 64
      9 
---> 10 history = model.fit(
     11     X_train,
     12     y_train,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    886         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    887         # stateless function.
--> 888         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    889     else:
    890       _, _, _, filtered_flat_args = \

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2940       (graph_function,
   2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
   2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2944 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1916         and executing_eagerly):
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    553       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    554         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 555           outputs = execute.execute(
    556               str(self.signature.name),
    557               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNNV2' used by {{node sequential/bidirectional/forward_cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNNV2}} with these attrs: [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", seed2=0, is_training=true]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]

     [[sequential/bidirectional/forward_cu_dnnlstm/CudnnRNNV2]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5956]




# Prediction

y_hat = model.predict(X_test)

y_test_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)
y_hat_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(y_hat)
 
plt.plot(y_test_inverse, label="Actual Price", color='green')
plt.plot(y_hat_inverse, label="Predicted Price", color='red')
 
plt.title('Bitcoin price prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time [days]')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.legend(loc='best')
 
plt.show();

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-b81bf8d6b99c> in <module>
      1 # Prediction
      2 
----> 3 y_hat = model.predict(X_test)
      4 
      5 y_test_inverse = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1627           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1628             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1629             tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
   1630             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1631               context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    892               *args, **kwds)
    893       # If we did not create any variables the trace we have is good enough.
--> 894       return self._concrete_stateful_fn._call_flat(
    895           filtered_flat_args, self._concrete_stateful_fn.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    896 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1916         and executing_eagerly):
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    553       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    554         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 555           outputs = execute.execute(
    556               str(self.signature.name),
    557               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNNV2' used by {{node sequential_1/bidirectional_3/forward_cu_dnnlstm_3/CudnnRNNV2}} with these attrs: [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", seed2=0, is_training=true]
Registered devices: [CPU]
Registered kernels:
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]

     [[sequential_1/bidirectional_3/forward_cu_dnnlstm_3/CudnnRNNV2]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_13727]
```

'''

Comment: Do you have a Cuda GPU in your system?  Is it a competent one, or a cheap one?

Comment: Here your registered devices showing only `CPU`. But above code only be run on `GPU`. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/layers/CuDNNLSTM). Either you can install GPU card in your system or you can use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb?utm_source=scs-index#scrollTo=5fCEDCU_qrC0) to run your code and also get free access to GPU.Thanks!